How to obtain i without dot?
I believed that i without dot was encoded by $\dotlessi$ from the package amssymb. Apparently, I am wrong. I have also tried $\i$ without success. It's because I want to use $\overline{i}$ and I think that removing the dot would look better.

How do I remove the dot in $\overline{i}$ ?


Give $\bar{\imath}$ a try.

For dotless i and j inside math, should use as \imath and \jmath
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\imath$\quad$\jmath$

\end{document}


If you use the package dotlessi you can use the command $\dotlessi$. Otherwise, as @MadyYuvi suggested, you can use $\imath$. So you would do: $\overline{\dotlessi}$ when importing the package or $\overline{\imath}$ if not importing the package.
Here is a MWE with different commands to produce dotless i and j:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dotlessi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        i/j  &     Package    &  Command    & Math mode?\\
        \hline
        i    & dotlessi       & $\dotlessi$ & Yes \\
        j    & dotlessi       & $\dotlessj$ & Yes\\
        i    & \LaTeX/ N/A    & $\imath$    & Yes \\
        j    & \LaTeX/ N/A    & $\jmath$    & Yes \\
        \hline
        i    & \LaTeX/ N/A    & \i          & No \\
        j    & \LaTeX/ N/A    & \j          & No \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

Overline: $\overline{\dotlessi}$, $\overline{\imath}$

\end{document}


You can read about the package here: https://ctan.org/pkg/dotlessi?lang=en

You could also do:
\newcommand{\ioverline}{\overline{\imath}}

and write $\ioverline$ instead (if you are going to use it often).
